# What is the significance of the name argument to WSGIDaemonProcess?

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsgi

[The first argument to WSGIDaemonProcess is name](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess) like so:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess name [ options ]
```

But what does that name map to or affect? Does it matter what it is? If so, to what does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

The name doesn't map to anything else, but other things map to that name.

In particular, if you don't actually have WSGIProcessGroup or process-group options on appropriate configuration directives with that name, then nothing will be delegated to use that set of processes for running the WSGI application. The need to use WSGIProcessGroup is mentioned in the documentation you refer to.

As to the value of name, that is up to you.